# Activemq VM Protocol - BrokerService Error

Tags: activemq-classic

I am getting an error while opening connection to the broker service with VM protocol.

```
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();

    try {
        broker.setPersistent(true);
        broker.setUseJmx(false);
        broker.setBrokerName("broker1");
        broker.start();

        while(true){

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is my producer;

```
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://broker1?create=false");
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
```

I am getting this error;

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Broker named 'broker1' does not exist.
at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:254)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:267)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:239)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:185)
at Client.main(Client.java:22)
```

Comment: Is the Connection being created from within the same VM?

Answer (score 1):

Tim you are right, connection was not created within the same jvm.I have realized my mistake